# Problem with Yum: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml

Tags: centos, package-management, yum

As the post subject suggests I have some issues with yum.

Disabling the Base repo only move the problem to the next repo; it happens to all repos.

The XML is returned as a valid xml when using curl.

What have I done so far (with no results):

1. yum clean
2. removing the mirror list from the CentOS-Base.repo
3. check the curl returns a valid xml
4. check the mirror list returns a valid response
5. add a proxy for in CentOS-Base.repo configuration
6. removed the proxy for in CentOS-Base.repo configuration
7. reinstalled yum, and plugins via local rpm
8. disabled plugins

It looks like I'm running out of options, help would be appreciated

**Error**

```
cento7:[~]: sudo yum update
Not loading "fastestmirror" plugin, as it is disabled
Not loading "langpacks" plugin, as it is disabled
Config time: 0.009
Yum version: 3.4.3
rpmdb time: 0.000
Updating Everything
Building updates object
Setting up Package Sacks
base                                                                                                       | 104 kB  00:00:00
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for base: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.

 One of the configured repositories failed (CentOS-7 - Base),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=base ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable base
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=base

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note
that yum will try to contact the repository when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=base.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for base: Damaged repomd.xml file
```

**/etc/yum.conf:**

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=10
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
#proxy=http://localhost:8888
```

**CentOS-Base.repo:**

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Comment: Try `yum clean all` and, for good measure, `rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*` . Then try again.

Comment: That's one of the first steps tat I tried, but thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am getting this error from last few days, started to suddenly occur sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was cause by filtering rules in the corporate firewall.